# How to arrange div elements under each other css

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Please help me to arrange div elements under each other such way they can look like a equalizer on this screenshots [Equalizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q3Gt.png), advice how to remove dots from the list. I already tried a common way to remove this dots using css property (list-style-type: none).

And one more thing, how to make this equalizer in gradient color, top to bottom from lighter to darker.

Thanks, in advance.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #333333;
}

li:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

ul li {
  background: linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
  margin: 5px;
}

.blocks {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Equalizer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="equalizer.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="blocks">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <!--<div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>-->
  </div>
  <div class="blocks">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <!--<div></div>
 <div></div>-->
  </div>
  <div class="blocks">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <!--<div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>-->
  </div>
  <div class="blocks">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>-->
  </div>
  <div class="blocks">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <!--<div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>-->
  </div>
  <div class="blocks">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <!--<div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider one element to achieve this layout and use height to control the size:

```css
body {
  background: #333333
}

.equ {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(transparent 80%, #333333 20%)0 0/100% 40px, 
  linear-gradient(orange, yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="equ">
</div>
<div class="equ" style="height:60px">
</div>
<div class="equ" style="height:220px">
</div>
<div class="equ" style="height:140px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS Grid, something like this: https://codepen.io/matt5409/pen/zWxVqK

The magic is in the grid layout:

```
.col{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3, 1fr); // repeat 3 columns
  grid-column-gap: 2px; // 2px gap between
  align-items: end; // ensure items align at the bottom
}
```

Comment: and what about the gradient ? which is the main issue

Comment: There are a few options - you could have the stacks transparent and put a gradient on the stack. Or add a gradient to each block. I just wanted to give an example of how you can achieve this sort of layout very easily with Grid.

Comment: am not the OP :) i know how to do it ;) but it should inside your question since the OP is asking for it

Comment: i'm tired and about to sleep! but there you go, i've updated the pen :P